# Angularjs : How to find value of a variable store in a string

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

It seems novice question but I am not able to figure it out how to find value of a variable store in a string e.g

```
var value = "Scope.address";
```

Actually I want to find the value of "Scope.address" how to find it.

Comment: Question is not clear.... you can try $scope.address

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to understand what you want.

If you want to access a variable address(in angular this might be model) you have to use $scope.address.

Here is the example

```
<input type="text" ng-model="address">
```

and the corresponding script to access address in controller is

```
var value=$scope.address;
```

**Updated**

```
var value2=$scope[value];
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsbin.com/cofalaqenure/1/edit)

Comment: no actual requirement is that I already have value = "$scope.address" but now I want to fetch the value2 which is the actual value of $scope.address through "value"

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference $scope from a location where $scope is available. One common location is your controller

```
var value = $scope.address;
```

If you need it to be dynamic try the following:

```
 var value = 'address';
 var myDynamicValue = $scope[value];
```

Comment: no actual requirement is that I already have value = "$scope.address" but now I want to fetch the value2 which is the actual value of $scope.address through "value"

Comment: The above code is how you would normally reference $scope

Comment: I agree but I want to fetch the value of $scope.address through a variable say tmp which has tmp="$scope.address" value . How to do it .

Comment: Ok. You can try $scope["address"]